# React-Native Button style not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-button

## Import_this

```jsx
import {AppRegistry, Text, View, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
```

This my React Button code But style not working Hare ...

```jsx
<Button
  onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} 
  title={"Go Back"}
  style={{color: 'red', marginTop: 10, padding: 10}}
/>
```

Also I was try by this code

```jsx
<Button 
       containerStyle={{padding:10, height:45, overflow:'hidden', 
       borderRadius:4, backgroundColor: 'white'}}
       style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}} 
       onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} title={"Go Back"}
      > Press me!
</Button>
```

## Update Question:

Also I was try by This way..

```jsx
<Button
    onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
    title={"Go Back"}
    style={styles.buttonStyle}
>ku ka</Button>
```

## Style

```jsx
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonStyle: {
        color: 'red',
        marginTop: 20,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
});
```

But No out put: 
Screenshot  of my phone:-
[image: Screenshot of my phone:-]

Comment: `Button` do you use custom component or react button component?

Comment: maybe react `button

Comment: It doesn't have `style` property. Please check once.

Answer (score 139):

The **React Native Button** is very limited in what you can do, see; [Button](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button)

It does not have a **style prop**, and you don't set text the "web-way" like `<Button>txt</Button>` but via the title property `<Button title="txt" />`

If you want to have more control over the appearance you should use one of the TouchableXXXX' components like [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)
They are really easy to use :-)

Comment: A working example with TouchableOpacity would be great.

Comment: hi..can you pls explain why button dont have style props?

Comment: [From the docs](//facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button): "If this button doesn't look right for your app, you can build your own button using [TouchableOpacity](/facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) or [TouchableNativeFeedback](//facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback). For inspiration, look at the [source code for this button component](//github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js). Or, take a look at the [wide variety of button components built by the community](https://js.coach/react-native?search=button)."

Answer (score 50):

I had an issue with margin and padding with a `Button`. I added Button inside a `View` component and apply your properties to the `View`.

```jsx
<View style={{margin:10}}>
<Button
  title="Decrypt Data"
  color="orange"
  accessibilityLabel="Tap to Decrypt Data"
  onPress={() => {
    Alert.alert('You tapped the Decrypt button!');
  }}
  />  
</View>
```

Comment: It works for some cases, such adding a "box shadow", it's then an overkill to create an own button. Sadly the way to go is creating the own button if one want to style the button itself such as dimensions, padding, text appearance, etc...

Answer (score 19):

React Native buttons are very limited in the option they provide.You can use TouchableHighlight or TouchableOpacity by styling these element and wrapping your buttons with it like this

```jsx
             <TouchableHighlight 
                style ={{
                    height: 40,
                    width:160,
                    borderRadius:10,
                    backgroundColor : "yellow",
                    marginLeft :50,
                    marginRight:50,
                    marginTop :20
                }}>
            <Button onPress={this._onPressButton}            
            title="SAVE"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this button"
          /> 
          </TouchableHighlight>
```

You can also use react library for customised button .One nice library is react-native-button (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-button)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Depressed to see that we need to install a library to work with a  button.

Answer (score 13):

If you do not want to create your own button component, a quick and dirty solution is to wrap the button in a view, which allows you to at least apply layout styling.

For example this would create a row of buttons:

```jsx
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex:1 , marginRight:10}} >
        <Button title="Save" onPress={() => {}}></Button>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}} >
        <Button title="Cancel" onPress={() => {}}></Button>
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using button . you can use Text in react native and then make in touchable

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}> 
   <Text style = {'your custome style'}>
       button name
   </Text>
</TouchableOpacity >
```

Answer (score 7):

**Style in button will not work, You have to give style to the view.**

```
<View style={styles.styleLoginBtn}>
          <Button
            color="orange" //button color
            onPress={this.onPressButton}
            title="Login"
          />
        </View>
```

**Give this style to view**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  styleLoginBtn: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginRight: 50,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderColor: "black", //button background/border color
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Pressable` with `Text` instead of button.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable } from 'react-native';

<Pressable style={styles.button} onPress = {() => console.log("button pressed")}> 
  <Text style={styles.text}>Press me</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Example Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 32,
    borderRadius: 4,
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    letterSpacing: 0.25,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Only learning myself, but wrapping in a View may allow you to add styles around the button.

```jsx
const Stack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeView,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home View'
    }
  },
  CoolView: {
    screen: CoolView,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: 'Cool View',
      headerRight: (<View style={{marginRight: 16}}><Button
        title="Cool"
        onPress={() => alert('cool')}
      /></View>
    )
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This one

```jsx
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressAppoimentButton()} style={styles.Btn}>
    <Button title="Order Online" style={styles.Btn} > </Button>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `buttonStyle` prop now.
https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html#buttonstyle

Answer (score 1):

As the answer by @plaul mentions `TouchableOpacity`, here is an example of how you can use that;

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={someStyles}
    onPress={doSomething}
  >
    <Text>Press Here</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

**SUGGESTION:**

I will recommend using `react-native-paper` components as they are modified and can be modified much more than `react-native` components.

To install;
npm install react-native-paper

Then you can simply import them and use.

More details here [Here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

button styles does'nt work in react-native, to style your button in react-native easy way is to put it inside the **View** block like this:

```
      <View
         style={styles.buttonStyle}>
         <Button
         title={"Sign Up"}
         color={"#F31801"}/>
      </View>
```

**style.buttonStyle** be like this:

```
style.buttonStyle{
        marginTop:30,
        marginLeft:50,
        marginRight:50,
        borderWidth:2,
        borderRadius:20,
        borderColor:'#F31801',
        overflow:"hidden",
        marginBottom:10,
}
```

, it will make you able to use designs with buttons

Answer (score 1):

React-native button is very limited, it won't allow styling. use react native elements button or create custom button

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the button component inside a view component and change the styles of the view component, it should work. Please refer to the snippet below

```
     <View style={{width: 150, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
       <Button onPress={demoFunction} title="clickMe!!" />
     </View>
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is necro-posting, but I found a real easy way to just add the margin-top and margin-bottom to the button itself without having to build anything else.

When you create the styles, whether inline or by creating an object to pass, you can do this:

```
var buttonStyle = {
   marginTop: "1px",
   marginBottom: "1px"
}
```

It seems that adding the quotes around the value makes it work.  I don't know if this is because it's a later version of React versus what was posted two years ago, but I know that it works now.